# Sum instead of concatenation

Tags: javascript

I have my code

```
sum=parseFloat($('input[name=fieldname]').val()) * 60 + 
parseFloat($('input[name=fieldname]').val()) + 
(($('input[name=fieldname]').val()) /60).toFixed(2).
```

It get's the values from felds where I enter duration and it should give me the sum in minutes.
The problem is that the sum I get concatenates the 3 fields instead of returning the number of minutes.

Eg: for 1 hours and 20 minutes I get 6020 instead of (60+20) 80

Edit: The code above is the generic form, here is the exact code.

```
var sum = parseFloat($('input[name="<?php esc_attr_e( $field->field_id ); ?>hrs"]').val())*60 +
parseFloat(($('input[name="<?php esc_attr_e( $field->field_id ); ?>mins"]').val()) + 
parseFloat($('input[name="<?php esc_attr_e( $field->field_id ); ?>secs"]').val())/60).toFixed(2)
```

Comment: Why do you use `$('input[name=fieldname]').val()` thrice?

Comment: @Bergi - +1. You know, I've always liked that word... "thrice"... so rarely have an opportunity to use it in a sentence.

Comment: It is a generic form of my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It concatenates because you still have a string in your statement. Let's shortcut the number conversion functions and just do it with straight syntax:

```
var h = $('input[name=hours]').val(),
    m = $('input[name=minutes]').val(),
    s = $('input[name=seconds]').val();
sum = 3600*(h|0) + 60*(m|0) + (s|0);
```

Comment: only if the page does, in which case you should probably have a milliseconds field, instead. var ms = $(...).val() and then sum = ... + (ms|0)/1000?

Comment: not my page; note that multiplication already converts to numbers so the first two casts are not strictly neccessary.

Answer (score 0):

[`toFixed()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) returns a string, and that is concatenated to the result of the previous calculation. Use this:

```
var input = parseFloat($('input[name=fieldname]').val());
sum = input * 60 + input + Math.round(input / 6000) * 100;
```

(works equivalent if you've got separate inputs, I think you get the idea)